# Aptitude depends

Tags: aptitude

How do i fix this?
I also did `sudo apt-get -f install` but same error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  aptitude: Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6) but it is not installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
            Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxapian22 but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Every command I try from there results the same think with "aptitude"

Comment: @ianyskd There are *a lot* of techniques presented there. For this question not to be considered a duplicate of that one, please edit your question to expand it with detailed information about everything you tried and *exactly* what happened.